# Upload React native app as an Update of the Native Android app

Tags: android, react-native

My native android app has 15k+ downloads and now I want to migrate to the React-native app as an update of my existing app. Can I upload React native code at the same app means my Userbase and Reviews should be as it is? After React native app live it display the same downloads and Review? Also, My app has a Subscription plan. is that also remain the same?

Comment: I think it would be fine if you used the same Application ID

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a new React Native application will work, provided you set the same package name. You will also need to keep the same keystore to sign the new application. If you do this correctly then you shouldn't face any problems when uploading to Google Play.